# rdfs remove items if a condition happens

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl

In a previous question

[SPARQL if an instance has a property, others must as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770272/sparql-if-an-instance-has-a-property-others-must-as-well)

I asked that if i have an instance that has a value for a specific predicate, then the all the output of my sparql query must have the same value for the same predicate.

I got an excellent answer there,

now I am trying to expand it because i've found a new scenario,

the new scenario is:

if an instance has a value to a *specific predicate* then all the output items must either have the same value for the same predicate or **if they have another value, these two values must be from the same class**

I extended that sparql query to the following:

```sql
    PREFIX : <http://example.org/rs#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?item ?predicate ?similarity where 
{
  values ?x {:instance1}
  ?x ?predicate ?value.
  ?item ?predicate ?value.
  ?predicate :hasSimilarityValue ?similarity.
  filter (?x != ?item)
  filter not exists {
    ?x ?p ?v1.
    ?v1 a   ?class.
    ?p  rdfs:subPropertyOf  :isCriticalPredicate.
    filter not exists {
        ?item ?p ?v2.
        ?p rdfs:subPropertyOf :isCriticalPredicate.
        ?v2 a   ?class.
        ?class  rdfs:subClassOf :ImportantClass
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my data:

```
  @prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

:instance1  :p1 :value1.
:instance2  :p1 :value2.
:p1 :hasSimilarityValue 0.5.
:value1 a   :class1.
:value2 a   :class1.
:class1 rdfs:subClassOf :ImportantClass.
:p1 rdfs:subPropertyOf  :isCriticalPredicate.
```

but the result is always empty i don't know why.

## note1

by specific predicate, i mean the predicate that are rdfs:subClassOf :isCriticalPredicate

by specific class, I mean that class that are rdfs:subClassOf :ImportantClass

Comment: Be careful with `:isCriticalPredicate.`  That `.` at the end can be significant, since things like `:foo.bar` are legal.  Make sure you have space between `:isCriticalPredicate` and `.`.

Comment: *"by specific class, I mean that class that are rdfs:subClassOf :ImportantClass"*  You don't mention a "specific class" anywhere earlier;  you say that *"if they have another value, these two values must be from the same class"*  Which do you actually want?  They must be values from the same class, or they must both be values from ImportantClass?

Comment: Your query starts with: `?x ?predicate ?value. ` ?item ?predicate ?value.`.  In your same data, instance1 and instance2 don't have any values in common, so this part of the query never matches.  There aren't any results to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Immediate Problem:  There's No Matching Data!

As written, this is a pretty simple issue: there's actually no data that matches the query you've written.  As such, I don't think the data and query really reproduce the problem that  you're describing.  You query begins with

```
  values ?x {:instance1}
  ?x ?predicate ?value.
  ?item ?predicate ?value.
  filter (?x != ?item)
```

Your data has:

```
:instance1  :p1 :value1.
:instance2  :p1 :value2.
```

There are no possible values for ?instance.  The only candidate would be :instance2, but it doesn't have any values in common with :instance1, so there's no candidate for ?value.

### The Query You Want

Now, even though the question as written doesn't really have the issue that you're describing, I think I see what you're asking about.   When you're trying to create minimal data for your debugging process, you should try to include **all the relevant cases**.  In this case, you'd want to have at least an instance that has the same value for a critical predicate, and an instance that has a different value for a critical predicate but where both values are important.  Here's some data:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:instance1 :p :v1 .
:instance1 :q :v2 .

:instance2 :p :v1 . 
:instance2 :q :v2 .  #-- same value for :q

:instance3 :p :v1 .
:instance3 :q :v3 .  #-- different, but important, value for :q

:instance4 :p :v1 .
:instance4 :q :v4 .  #-- different, non-important, value for :q

:q a :CriticalPredicate .

:v2 a :ImportantValue .
:v3 a :ImportantValue .
```

Given the query that you're already working with, I think this one will be relatively clear.  It's not much different from what you've already got.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select distinct ?item where  {
  values ?x { :instance1 }
  ?x    ?predicate ?value .
  ?item ?predicate ?value .
  filter (?x != ?item)

  #-- Exclude any results where
  #-- ?x has a value ?v1 for a
  #-- critical predicate ?p...
  filter not exists {
    ?x ?p ?v1 .
    ?p a :CriticalPredicate .

    #-- ...unless either ?item has
    #-- the same value ?v1 for the
    #-- predicate ?p, or ?item has
    #-- another value ?v2 and both
    #-- ?v1 and ?v2 are
    #-- :ImportantValues.
    filter not exists {
      { ?item ?p ?v1 }
      union
      { ?item ?p ?v2 .
        :ImportantValue ^a ?v1, ?v2 . }
    }
  }
}
```

```
--------------
| item       |
==============
| :instance2 |
| :instance3 |
--------------
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the whole answer, i noticed that i did mistake in the providing data, i forgot to correct it on the question sorry. I am trying to understand the query, kindly what did you mean the `^a`, this is the first time i see this.

Comment: @Ania it's just a backwards property path.  In sparql and turtle you can use "a" instead of rdf:type. "X ^p Y, Z." Is just shorthand for "Y rdf:type X. Z rdf:type X." Saves a bit of typing.